# How to load a powershell module with a dynamic path?

Tags: powershell

I can load a module in powershell like that:

```
$ModuleName = $ScriptDir + "\functions.ps1"
. $ModuleName
```

But how to do this in one single line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're [dot-sourcing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847841.aspx) a PowerShell script (extension `.ps1`), not importing a (script) module (extension `.psm1`).

You can do it in a single line like this:

```
. "$ScriptDir\functions.ps1"
```

or like this:

```
. (Join-Path $ScriptDir 'functions.ps1')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write something like this:
`Join-Path $ScriptDir "\functions.psm1" | Import-Module`

So first safely combine the scriptdir and scriptname together and then use that for importing the module.